# How to pair strings inside a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, and I want to pair them in such a way that the last and second last is one pair, second last and third last in one pair and so on with a three dots in between.

#### Example:

Let's say I have the following list

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

and I want to convert this into something like this

```
['e...d', 'd...c', 'c...b', 'b...a', 'a...none']
```

So far I have done the following,

```
>>> import string
>>>
>>> letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:5]
>>> letters = iter(reversed(letters))
>>> pair_iter = (c + '...' + next(letters, 'none') for c in letters)
>>> pair_iter = list(pair_iter)
>>> pair_iter
['e...d', 'c...b', 'a...none']
```

I am not sure what else to do in this case, I do know that `next` go to the next string, but how should I copy the previous one and then go to the next one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a comprehension like:

#### Code:

```
list(reversed(['{}..{}'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(s, ['none'] + s[:-1])]))
```

#### Test Code:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print(list(reversed(['{}..{}'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(s, ['none'] + s[:-1])])))
```

#### Result:

```
['e..d', 'd..c', 'c..b', 'b..a', 'a..none']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use indexing with increments:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
new_s = s[::-1]
final_s = ['{}..{}'.format(new_s[i], new_s[i+1]) for i in range(len(new_s)-1)]+['{}..{}'.format(new_s[-1], 'none')]
```

Output:

```
['e..d', 'd..c', 'c..b', 'b..a', 'a..none']
```

Comment: is there any performance difference between the accepted answer and this one?